# Getting JSON in loop doesn't fetch all of the elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, callback

I'm trying to get elements from my JSON API like in a example below.
The thing is it doesn't work properly. I'm getting only values from One Hub instead from all of them.

/api/hubsUser/:id - returs JSON with all my hubs and 
/api/sensorsHub/:id - returns JSON with all my sensors which have hubID element.

```
var tableContent = '';
var wholeContent = '';
var hubList = [];

$.getJSON('/api/hubsUser/' + document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML, function (result) {

    $.each(result.data, function () {
        //alert(this.hubID);
        hubList.push(this.hubID);
    });

    $.each(hubList, function (i, hub) {
        // alert(hub);
        $.getJSON('/api/sensorsHub/' + hub, function (data) {

            $.each(data.data, function () {
                //alert(this.sensorID);
                tableContent += '<tr>';
                tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.sensorID + '">' + this.sensorID + '</a></td>';
                tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.hubID + '">' + this.hubID + '</a></td>';
                tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.desc + '">' + this.desc + '</a></td>';
                tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.state + '">' + this.state + '</a></td>';
                tableContent += '</tr>';
            });
            wholeContent += tableContent;

        });
    });
    $('#sensorList table tbody').html(wholeContent);
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because after first ajax succeeds you make a lot of other ajax calls, async of course, and you don't wait for them to execute before you call `$('#sensorList table tbody').html(wholeContent);`. Strange you even get that one, probably because you are yet on localhost.

You should call `$('#sensorList table tbody').html(wholeContent)` after all your ajax calls return result. I think a route to follow is to use jQuery `when` option ([see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)) or 'promises'.

Another thing that you probably had in mind is to use `var tableContent = ''` in every secondary ajax instead of declaring it once in the beginning. Otherwise it will contain results of previous ajax calls and same content will be added to `wholeContent` multiple times.

Comment: or use `append` and add another append in the inner loop if order isn't important

Comment: To be honest I don't quit know how to implement this with `when` and `jQuery.Deferred`methods. Problematic is the `$.each` method, because I don't know how to add when or done callback to it.

Comment: Then do as @charlietfl suggested - move `$('#sensorList table tbody').append(wholeContent);` right below `wholeContent += tableContent;`. And don't forget to place `var tableContent = ''` before `$.each(data.data, function () {`

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions. Everything is working now.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `.bind(this)` to your `$.each` loops:

```
$.each(result.data, function () {
   //alert(this.hubID);
   hubList.push(this.hubID);
}.bind(this)); // <- force the loop to use the object context of your choice
```

Comment: @charlietfl - `this` is always an object instance, so I don't understand what you're inferring; which object it refers to is the problem. By using `bind`, you can force the context.